# Navigate between components inside <page-router-outlet>

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

How do I navigate between components inside the `<pager-router-outlet>` tag? I'm new to Nativescript.

I have a nativescript (with Angular 2) application. It contains a navbar (tabview) which uses `<page-router-outlet>` for every tab item (file: app.component.html).

Inside the home tab, I have a feed of userposts. There is a flying action button which should navigate to another component, where you can add a userpost. I want to have a function in the ts file which navigates to the other component.

app.component.html (Navbar)

```
<TabView 
    androidTabsPosition="bottom"
    tabBackgroundColor="white"
    class="font-awesome icon">

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: '&#xf015;'}"
        name="homeTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: '&#xf002;'}"
        name="searchTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: '&#xf19d;' }"
        name="educationTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: '&#xf0f3;'}"
        name="notificationTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: '&#xf007;'}"
        name="profileTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

</TabView>
```

home.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
 import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
 import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
 import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
 import { CardView } from "nativescript-cardview";
 import { isAndroid } from "tns-core-modules/platform";
 import { CourseService } from "~/app/services/course/course.service";
 import { EventService } from "~/app/services/event/event.service";
 import { PostService } from "~/app/services/post/post.service";

registerElement("CardView", () => CardView);
registerElement("PullToRefresh", () => require("nativescript-            pulltorefresh").PullToRefresh);

@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    providers: [PostService, CourseService, EventService],
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
    styleUrls: [ "./home.css", "../../css/global.css",     "../../css/button.css", "../../css/card.css" ]
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    posts: Array<any>;

    constructor(
    private postService: PostService,
    private courseService: CourseService,
    private eventService: EventService,
    private router: RouterExtensions,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        // Code
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.posts = this.postService.getPosts();
    }

    navigateToAddPost() {
        this.router.navigate(["addPost"]); // this function doesnt work
    }

    refreshList(args) {
        const pullRefresh = args.object;
        // tslint:disable-next-line:only-arrow-functions
        setTimeout(function() {
           pullRefresh.refreshing = false;
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

addPost.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { PostService } from "~/app/services/post/post.service";

@Component({
    selector: "addPost",
    moduleId: module.id,
    providers: [PostService],
    templateUrl: "./addPost.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["../../../css/global.css", "../../../css/button.css", "../../../css/card.css"]
})

export class AddPostComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private postService: PostService
    ) {
        // Code
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Code
    }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

import { EducationComponent } from "./pages/education/education.component";
import { AddPostComponent } from "./pages/home/addPost/addPost.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./pages/home/home.component";
import { ItemDetailComponent } from "./pages/item-detail/item-detail.component";
import { NotificationComponent } from "./pages/notification/notification.component";
import { ProfileComponent } from "./pages/profile/profile.component";
import { SearchComponent } from "./pages/search/search.component";

export const COMPONENTS = [
    EducationComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ItemDetailComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    NotificationComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    AddPostComponent
];

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "",
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
      redirectTo:         "/(homeTab:home//educationTab:education//searchTab:search//notificationTab:notification//profileTab:profile)",
  pathMatch: "full"
    },

    { path: "home", component: HomeComponent, outlet: "homeTab" },
    { path: "education", component: EducationComponent, outlet: "educationTab" },
    { path: "search", component: SearchComponent, outlet: "searchTab" },
    { path: "notification", component: NotificationComponent, outlet: "notificationTab" },
    { path: "profile", component: ProfileComponent, outlet: "profileTab" },

    { path: "addPost", component: AddPostComponent},

    { path: "item/:id", component: ItemDetailComponent, outlet: "homeTab" }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I want to have a function in home.component.ts that navigates to addPost.component

Comment: you should only use a `page-router-outlet` in the app.component.html file as the top most level tag, everywhere else you need to use `router-outlet`'s

Comment: So I should replace the `page-router-outlet` with `router-outlet` in app.component.html inside one `page-router-outlet` tag?

Comment: no, your app.component.html file should just be `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`, then you need a page with your current app.component.html code in

Comment: @mast3rd3mon @Akrime You may use any number of page-router-outlet in your application, where ever you want, that was the whole purpose of introducing multi frame support in {N} v4. But when you have multiple `page-router-outlets` active at one level, you must pass url segments for all outlets. You must select an outlet for `addPost` / `AddPostComponent` as there are multiple, if you are planning to open it as a detail page within home tab then it should be a child route inside `home` route. Refer the [Github examples](https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng) for more details.

Comment: @Manoj you can use as many as you want, but you shouldnt. you should only use 1, and it should be in your app.component.html file. having more within that (child routing etc) typically causes obscure and irritating errors

Comment: @mast3rd3mon You could check the TabView hello world example yourself Or even visit the link in my comment above where they have even more complex nested router setup.

Comment: @Manoj and you should try nesting (not siblings) `page-router-outlets` and see for yourself the issues it causes. its because its not designed to work like that

Comment: I'm already using nested `page-router-outlets`, at least I didn't find any issues in recent releases but I had issues in older versions ({N} Angular 6.x). Haven't had a chance to try siblings though for myself.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, do you have working exmple of router-outlets inside page-router-outlet? This is what I'm currently looking for. In my project it causes issue with back navigation.